# Is there a good reason to initialize a property in the SetParameters method rather than directly?

Tags: blazor

In the code snippet below, taken from a Blazor sample, the StartDate property is initialized in the derived SetParameters method while it could be initialized thus:

```
[Parameter] DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

I wonder if this is a matter of style preference only, or there is a good reason to do so...

```
  @functions {
    [Parameter] DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    public override void SetParameters(ParameterCollection parameters)
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        base.SetParameters(parameters);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the blazor [documentation](https://blazor.net/docs/components/index.html#lifecycle-methods):

*`SetParameters` can be overridden to execute code before parameters are set.*

*If base.SetParameters isn't invoked, the custom code can interpret the incoming parameters value in any way required. For example, the incoming parameters aren't required to be assigned to the properties on the class.*

So `SetParameters` allows you to sneaky modify stuff..

I'm guessing that you are setting the value to have a default. For that I would say that the first method is perfectly fine, and the second method overkill and confusing.

Comment: calling SetParameters above is taken from the Blazor sample, probably created by danroth or SteveSandersonMS...and I was wondering why they did it that way, as in previous samples, they've initialized the property itself. However, do you think this is related to the fact that the sample code calls OnParametersSetAsync instead of OnInitAsync ? Thanks for your response...